# Stability region of midpoint method using Solve and RegionPlot

Tags: equation-solving, plotting, stability

I've been trying to obtain the stability region in the $(\lambda_R, i\lambda_I)$ plane of the midpoint rule $$y_{n+1}= y_{n-1}+2h\dot{y}_n,$$ for the model problem $\dot{y}=\lambda y$.  The roots for the characteristic polynomial when $y_n=x^n$ are $$x_{1,2}=h\lambda \pm \sqrt{1+h^2\lambda^2} $$ So what I need is to find what values of $\lambda=\lambda_R+i\lambda_I$ satisfy the conditions $|x_1| \leq 1$ and $|x_2|\leq 1$ simultanously. I know from literature that it is found to be a segment in the imaginary axis: $(-i,i)$, but I wanted to find it myself. I tried with:

```
Solve[Abs[(x + I y) + Sqrt[1 + (x + I y)^2]] <=  1 && 
      Abs[(x + I y) - Sqrt[1 + (x + I y)^2]] <= 1, {x, y}, Complexes]
```

It doesn't work, the evaluation never ends. I'm also interested in the plot of the region of stability, which I should find with RegionPlot as follows:

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate@ComplexExpand[Abs[z - Sqrt[1 + z^2]] <= 1 /. z -> x + I y] && 
           Evaluate@ComplexExpand[Abs[z + Sqrt[1 + z^2]] <= 1 /. z -> x + I y], 
           {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

But is shows a blank plot, I'm guessing it could be because I'm trying to display a segment and not a "region" per se.
Any thoughts and help will be greatly appreciated.
Cheers,
Franco.

Comment: `Show[RegionPlot[(Abs[(x + I y) + Sqrt[1 + (x + I y)^2]] <= 1), {x, -2,
    2}, {y, -2, 2}], 
 RegionPlot[
  Abs[(x + I y) - Sqrt[1 + (x + I y)^2]] <= 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
   PlotStyle -> Red]]`

Comment: Thanks belisarius, that shows both regions but the "overlapping" region (which shouldn't be the whole imaginary axis, just the $(-i,i)$ semgment) is still not clear to me.

Comment: `Plot3D[{Abs[(x + I y) + Sqrt[1 + (x + I y)^2]], 
  Abs[(x + I y) - Sqrt[1 + (x + I y)^2]]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]`

Comment: Excellent! I still need to find the solution analytically, with Solve or something similar, but this helps a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you want only real solutions. Which does not make your method wrong since you could later extract the real ones.